# Eclipselink - allocationSize property for TableGenerator

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I am using `EclipseLink` for a small project to record user activities. I have a class that captures details about the activity and I am using the table generator strategy to generate the primary key ids for that class.

The issue I am facing is that `EclipseLink` (I will call it *EL*) is assigning primary keys at an increment of 50 which I understand is the default value for the `allocationSize`. This is within the same JVM cycle (i.e., no reboot).

I understood that the `allocationSize` is used for the number of IDs *EL* would pre-allocate in memory. I would like to use this functionality, but *EL* doesn't seem to be working like that.

Only when I change the `allocationSize` to *1* do I get *EL* to generate Primary Keys sequentially.

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

I am using `EclipseLink` *2.3.0*.

Comment: Can you explain what isn't working a bit more?  Setting it to 1 tells EclipsLink it needs to go to the table for each sequence.  How are you trying to use it?

Comment: Even with an allocation size of 50, the ids will still be assigned more or less sequentially unless you close your EntityManagerFactory.  Include your code and persistence.xml

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. I have solved my problem. I was manually managing the lifecycle of the `EntityManager` and the transactions as well. I changed my code to have the `EntityManager` injected into my EJB and let the container take care of the transactions. I have set the allocationSize to 1000 and getting the desired results. Once again, thanks vels4j, Chris, and James for your help.

Comment: @westendraider Could you put your solution into an answer for this question and mark it resolved?  It makes it easier to hunt down genuinely open questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your help.

I have solved my problem. I was manually managing the lifecycle of the EntityManager and the transactions as well. I changed my code to have the EntityManager injected into my EJB and let the container take care of the transactions. I have set the allocationSize to 1000 and getting the desired results. Once again, thanks vels4j, Chris, and James for your help